# TRichEdit doesn't allow typing with some fonts

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, richedit

I noticed that TRichEdit is acting strange. It works perfectly fine when I use usual fonts such as Arial, Verdana, Times New Roman.

However, if I change to some other font:

```
RichEdit1.Font.Name:='Viner Hand ITC'; // and many other fonts
```

RichEdit displays the current text fine but I can't type new letters using this font! New letters are displayed with a usual font (probably Tahoma).

[image]

What is the problem with unusual fonts? How to solve this strange behavior?

(I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 VCL)

**UPDATE:** It appears the problem is not related to Delphi. The same executable runs perfectly fine in my Windows 11. There's something wrong in my Windows 10.

Comment: A RichEdit control supports formatting. That is, different parts can have different fonts, colours, sizes, styles, etc. (You can also have advanced paragraph formatting, hyperlinks, tables, images, mathematical formulae, text boxes, OLE objects, etc.) You are looking for `RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Font.Name`.

Comment: (But I cannot reproduce your issue at all in 10.4.) Surely, if you put the caret within the `Rich|Edit` part, you will get the Viner font?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you for your response but I can reproduce the issue in 10.4. If I put the caret within the RichEdit1 part, it still types using Tahoma. Please try using the font "MV Boli" or "Viner Hand ITC".

Comment: Yes, I tried it with "Viner Hand ITC".

Comment: Are you perhaps using VCL styles ("VCL themes")?

Comment: I can not reproduce in Delphi 10.4 CE, not even if styles are applied (tested with "Obsidian"). Please add the `.dfm` content to your post.

Comment: Are you sure you have specified font installed on your computer? I'm noticing that if you specify invalid font name no error is raised and current font remains.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes it is installed. I just tried it in Windows 11 and it works perfectly. I think the problem is related to Windows 10. Thank you all...

Comment: The mentioned `Viner Hand ITC` font  does not come preinstalled neither with Windows 10 nor Windows 11 for that matter. Based on information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/viner-hand-itc#products-that-supply-this-font) this font gets installed as [Cloud Font](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-fonts-in-office-f7b009fe-037f-45ed-a556-b5fe6ede6adb?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) meaning that if you don't have latest Office installed and are not using Microsoft cloud services it might not get downloaded and installed on your computer at all. ...

Comment: ... So yeah chances that your Windows 10 computer doesn't have `Viner Hand ITC` font installed are quite high. If I were you I would not develop my application to rely on a specific non common font unless I ship the font with the application itself. But in order to do that you do need to get proper licence for specific font which sometimes may not be easy.

Comment: But @Silver , preinstalled or not, asker clearly has the font as you can see from the image. (and so do I, but, well, I also have MSO 2007).

Comment: I'm running Win 10, and cannot reproduce your problem. I don't think it has anything to do with specifically Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit I found out what the problem is.

You are modifying the individual property of the "RichEdit.Font" object. Unfortunately this means that `RichEdit` as a component isn't notified that any change has been made.

What you need to do is create your own `TFont` object set its parameter and then assign it to `RichEdit.Font` property.

```
var Fnt: TFont;
begin
  Fnt := TFont.Create;
  Fnt.Name := 'Viner Hand ITC';
  RichEdit1.Font := Fnt;
end;
```

This way `RichEdit` updates its font correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem for me. I'm exactly sure my computers have the font by the way :)